# How to display the value of a variable inside a listings environment

Tags: listings

I assigned the value `42` to the variable `\xVar`. Is it possible to display the value `42` using the variable `\xVar` inside a listings environment `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}`?

**My Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\xVar}{42}

\begin{document} 

  \begin{lstlisting}
     the value of xVar is \xVar
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\xVar}{42}

\begin{document} 

  \begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!]
     the value of xVar is !\xVar!
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: the value of xVar is 42]

See section “4.3.13 Escaping to LaTeX” in the `listings` manual for more information about option `escapechar` and the alternatives.

One more alternative would be to use, e.g., package `alltt` instead of `listings`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt}

\newcommand{\xVar}{42}

\begin{document} 

  \begin{alltt}
     the value of xVar is \xVar
  \end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

[image: the value of xVar is 42]